# Error: no operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++

I am having troubles getting this piece of code to work. I have included already:

```
#Include <string>
```

First Code Attempt:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if(i == Scroll)
        {
            Text[i] = "~y~[ " << Text[i] << " ~y~]";
            Text[i].R = 255; Text[i].G = 255; Text[i].B = 0; Text[i].A = 255;
        }
        else
        {
            Text[i].R = 255; Text[i].G = 255; Text[i].B = 255; Text[i].A = 255;
        }
    }
```

Second Code Attempt:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if(i == Scroll)
        {
            std::string br1;
            std::string br2;
            br1 = "~y~[ ";
            br2 =  " ~y~]";
            Text[i] = br1 << Text[i] << br2;
            Text[i].R = 255; Text[i].G = 255; Text[i].B = 0; Text[i].A = 255;
        }
        else
        {
            Text[i].R = 255; Text[i].G = 255; Text[i].B = 255; Text[i].A = 255;
        }
    }
```

Neither of them see to work and I get the error at the "<<" saying, "no operator "<<" matches these operands"

Comment: I am trying to get the [ ] to be around the Text[i] so If the text is "Hello" then it will show as [ Hello ]

Comment: `<<` is not the string concatenation operator, it's the stream output operator, but you're not using streams.

Comment: Also, what is the type of `Text`? How can you be doing `Text[i] = (string)` followed by `Text[i].R = `?

Comment: I also tried + instead of << but same error.

Comment: The Text[i] is the text and the rest are properties so they are for RGBA coloring

Comment: Bryan, what is the definition of `Text`? Please post that line.

Comment: Better yet, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a complete error message (this one is not).

Comment: It doesn't *really* matter what `Text[i]` specifically is at this point. We know it's not a `string` from the code, and we know that no `<<` or `+` operators are defined for it from the problem description. We also know that the OP is, for some reason, expecting it to behave like a string. Its exact type won't add any new info, although should have been posted to begin with.

Comment: Why did this question get negative votes?

Comment: @EvanCarslake I'm presuming because folks are preoccupied with the specific type of `Text` even though it's somewhat moot. Of course, it should have been presented to begin with, many understandably don't like having to hunt through code to dig up info. Either that or the apparent lack of effort in finding solutions, but that may be understandable for a new programmer here.

Comment: @EvanCarslake, It does fit the "unclear" part given that there was no way to know if your answer was right without extra information. The fact that + gives the same error is helpful in that regard.

Comment: @EvanCarslake negative votes are because it is unclear and not useful. Good questions in the category of "this doesn't work" should contain a MCVE. As posted, the question cannot be definitively answered because nobody knows what `Text` is.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.

Problem #1: If `Text[i]` *were* a `string`, and you have:

```
Text[i] = br1 << Text[i] << br2;
```

`<<` is generally used for stream concatenation, or bit shifting, among other things. Unless you've defined one, there isn't a `<<` operator that takes a `string` on both sides, hence the error.

You'd probably mean:

```
Text[i] = br1 + Text[i] + br2;
```

However, problem #2 is `Text[i]` doesn't seem to be a string, given that you have:

```
Text[i].R = 255;
```

And so on. So if `Text[i]` is supposed to be some kind of string then you need to make it be a `string`; if you're trying to generate a string from whatever type `Text[i]` is, you'll need to define a function or operator that can do that. Nothing in C++ magically turns arbitrary classes and structs into strings for you.

Comment: The "+" still gives me an error, "no operator "+" matches these operands"

Comment: @Bryan Right, because of problem #2.

Answer (score 1):

For concatenating strings use + not <<

```
Text[i] = "~y~[ " + Text[i] + " ~y~]";
```

Comment: The "+" still gives me an error, "no operator "+" matches these operands"

Comment: @Bryan: That's the first line of the error.  Click on the error, then view the "Output" window (Alt+2), and tell us the _entire_ error.